# SafeHtmlCell column is not firing the handler onBrowserEvent

Tags: java, gwt

In gwt cell table column,i created a column of type SafeHtmlCell.Inside i overridden the `getvalue()` and `onBrowserEvent()` Method. But when i click the column its not firing the event.See the below

```
 @Override
 public SafeHtml getValue(final Object object) {
 SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
 sb.appendHtmlConstant("<B>");
 sb.appendHtmlConstant(value);
 sb.appendHtmlConstant("</B>");
 sb.appendHtmlConstant("<i class='icon-pencil'></i></span>");
 return sb.toSafeHtml();
      }

   @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem,
                        Object object, NativeEvent event) {
           if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
           EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
            if (elem.isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
            Element el = Element.as(eventTarget);
            if ("icon-pencil".equals(el.getClassName())) {
                        Window.alert("Successfully clicked");
                                                        }
                                        }
                            }
                    }
```

How to solve this? Wether i need override `render()` Method as well?

Comment: Please share the full class, as well as how you are attaching it to its cell widget.

Comment: i just overriden the above getvalue() and onBrowserEvent inside the SafeHtmlCell() column ..

Comment: And how do you use this class, how do you attach it to its cell widget? Does your class have a constructor?

Comment: Thanks Colin Alworth for your suggestion..I solved it..

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom cell, you need to override the `render` method (not the `getValue` method) and put your HTML inside the `SafeHtmlBuilder sb` parameter.

Then if you want to listen for event, you need to override `onBrowserEvent` (as you have done), but you also need to specify the `consumedEvents` in the constructor of you class.

Example for your case:

```
public class TestCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

  public TestCell() {
    super("click");
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
                           NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
      Window.alert("clicked");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<B>");
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(value);
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</B>");
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<i class='icon-pencil'></i></span>");
  }
}
```

Comment: If i put this inside the render method,then the output will be appending to its already value like....(value+sb.appendHtmlConstant("<B>");sb.appendHtmlConstant(value);........),

Comment: I used `extends AbstractCell` not `extends SafeHtmlCell` in my exemple.

Answer (score 0):

`SafeHtmlCell` don't have click event so i created my own custom class which extends `AbstractCell<SafeHtml>` and overridden `onBrowserEvent()`

```
public class CustomSafeHtmlCell extends AbstractCell<SafeHtml>{

    public CustomSafeHtmlCell(){
        super(BrowserEvents.CLICK);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if(value!=null){
            sb.append(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
      public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value, NativeEvent event,
          ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
        String eventType = event.getType();
        if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals(eventType)) {
        //logic...

        }
      }

}
```

and Used this CustomSafeHtmlCell instead of directly using SafeHtmlCell.